# How to add a self-defined MouseMotionListener to a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, mousemotionlistener

I wrote a `MouseMotionListener` for `JPanel`, but I get confused on how to use it.

The listener class works well when added to the frame using `aWindow.add(new MouseMotionEvents())`, but when I try to add it to the panel using `content.add(new MouseMotionEvents())`, it doesn't work. I am new to Swing and `JComponent`s, could someone give me some hints?

```java
public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame aWindow = new JFrame();
    aWindow.setBounds(600, 600, 600, 600);
    aWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.add(new MouseMotionEvents());
    aWindow.add(content);
    
    aWindow.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class MouseMotionEvents extends JPanel implements MouseListener,
    MouseMotionListener {
  Point p;
  Point r;

  public MouseMotionEvents() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    // p = me.getPoint();
    // repaint();
  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
  }

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    p = me.getPoint();
    // repaint();
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    r = me.getPoint();
    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    r = me.getPoint();
    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (p != null && r != null) {
      Dimension d = getSize();
      int xc = d.width / 2;
      int yc = d.height / 2;
      if(p.getX()-r.getX()>0 && p.getY()-r.getY()>0){
        g.drawRect((int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY(), (int)(p.getX()-r.getX()), (int)(p.getY()-r.getY()));
      }
      if(p.getX()-r.getX()>0 && p.getY()-r.getY()<0){
        g.drawRect((int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY(), (int)(p.getX()-r.getX()), (int)(-p.getY()+r.getY()));
      }
      if(p.getX()-r.getX()<0 && p.getY()-r.getY()>0){
        g.drawRect((int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY(), (int)(-p.getX()+r.getX()), (int)(p.getY()-r.getY()));
      }
      if(p.getX()-r.getX()<0 && p.getY()-r.getY()<0){
        g.drawRect((int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY(), (int)(-p.getX()+r.getX()), (int)(-p.getY()+r.getY()));
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Override paintComponent instead of paint.

Comment: If it still dosen't work, call invalidate() before repaint().

Comment: It's still doesn't work,

Comment: "It's still doesn't work" don't tell us what's not working. What's not working?

Comment: I just look through some other's post, and they use something like"jpanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() { ...  })", but the class i wrote just implements MouseListener and MouseMotionListener, do you think this is a problem?

Comment: No, that looks alright. And again, what is not working?

Comment: What I want to do is to add a MouseMotionListener to a Jpanel so i can use my mouse to draw a small rectangle on it. In my code, "aWindow" is a frame and if i use "aWindow.add(new MouseMotionEvents())" then i can draw a small rectangle, but if I use "content.add(new MouseMotionEvents())" where "content" is a Jpanel, i can't draw anything with mouse, I tried to add revalidate() as you commented earlier, but it also can't draw.

Answer (score 3):

In the code in your question, you are adding a `JPanel` to a `JPanel` since `MouseMotionEvents` is a `JPanel` (since it extends class `JPanel`). The default [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for `JPanel` is `FlowLayout` which tries to display its contained components at their preferred size. So when you run your GUI, you cannot really see where `MouseMotionEvents` appears. You can add a border to it by adding the following (in the constructor of class `MouseMotionEvents`)

```java
setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(java.awt.Color.red));
```

Now when you run the GUI, it looks like this

[image: original gui]

This is because a `JPanel` has zero (preferred) size because its size is determined by the components that it contains but in your code `MouseMotionEvents` contains no components. You can fix this by explicitly setting a preferred size. This is how it looks after setting an appropriate preferred size.

[image: preferred size]

Now you can drag the mouse inside the red border and rectangles will be drawn.

Also, you should override method `paintComponent` and not method `paint`. Refer to [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Here is the code.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MouseMotionEvents extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    Point p;
    Point r;

    public MouseMotionEvents() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        // p = me.getPoint();
        // repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("mousePressed");
        p = me.getPoint();
        // repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("mouseReleased");
        r = me.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        r = me.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (p != null && r != null) {
            Dimension d = getSize();
            int xc = d.width / 2;
            int yc = d.height / 2;
            if (p.x - r.x > 0 && p.y - r.y > 0) {
                g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, (p.x - r.x), (p.y - r.y));
            }
            if (p.x - r.x > 0 && p.y - r.y < 0) {
                g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, (p.x - r.x), (-p.y + r.y));
            }
            if (p.x - r.x < 0 && p.y - r.y > 0) {
                g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, (-p.x + r.x), (p.y - r.y));
            }
            if (p.x - r.x < 0 && p.y - r.y < 0) {
                g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, (-p.x + r.x), (-p.y + r.y));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame aWindow = new JFrame();
        aWindow.setBounds(600, 600, 600, 600);
        aWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.add(new MouseMotionEvents());
        aWindow.add(content);
        
        aWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Note that `x` and `y` are public members of class `Point` so no need to use methods `getX` and `getY` and therefore no need for casting.

When you added `MouseMotionEvents` directly to the `JFrame` you were adding `MouseMotionEvents` to a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` and you were adding it to the CENTER. Since you gave your `JFrame` and explicit size, the `BorderLayout` made sure that the size of `MouseMotionEvents` took up as much space as possible in the `JFrame`. Hence `MouseMotionEvents` was large enough that you could drag the mouse inside it.

Answer (score 0):

To add a MouseMotionListener to a JPanel, you have to use

```
myPanel.setMouseMotionListener ( myMouseListener );
```

and call that directly on your panel, as you did in the mouseMotionEvents class. Tht's why it's working, when you add this directly to your JFrame.

After fixing your code I got this, which should work perfectly fine. I splitted it in two classes, one main class with JFrame and one for the JPanel (content).

Main class:

```
public class MouseMotionListenerTest {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        JFrame aWindow = new JFrame();
        aWindow.setBounds( 600, 600, 600, 600 );
        aWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        ContentPanel content = new ContentPanel();
        aWindow.add( content );

        aWindow.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Panel class:

```
public class ContentPanel extends JPanel {
    private Point p;
    private Point r;

    public ContentPanel () {
        MouseMotionEvents mme = new MouseMotionEvents();
        addMouseListener( mme );
        addMouseMotionListener( mme );
    }

    public void paint ( Graphics g ) {
        if ( p != null && r != null ) {
            Dimension d = getSize();
            int xc = d.width / 2;
            int yc = d.height / 2;
            if ( p.getX() - r.getX() > 0 && p.getY() - r.getY() > 0 ) {
                g.drawRect( ( int ) p.getX(), ( int ) p.getY(), ( int ) ( p.getX() - r.getX() ), ( int ) ( p.getY() - r.getY() ) );
            }
            if ( p.getX() - r.getX() > 0 && p.getY() - r.getY() < 0 ) {
                g.drawRect( ( int ) p.getX(), ( int ) p.getY(), ( int ) ( p.getX() - r.getX() ), ( int ) ( -p.getY() + r.getY() ) );
            }
            if ( p.getX() - r.getX() < 0 && p.getY() - r.getY() > 0 ) {
                g.drawRect( ( int ) p.getX(), ( int ) p.getY(), ( int ) ( -p.getX() + r.getX() ), ( int ) ( p.getY() - r.getY() ) );
            }
            if ( p.getX() - r.getX() < 0 && p.getY() - r.getY() < 0 ) {
                g.drawRect( ( int ) p.getX(), ( int ) p.getY(), ( int ) ( -p.getX() + r.getX() ), ( int ) ( -p.getY() + r.getY() ) );
            }
        }
    }

    private class MouseMotionEvents extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked ( MouseEvent me ) {
            // p = me.getPoint();
            // repaint();
        }

        public void mousePressed ( MouseEvent me ) {
            p = me.getPoint();
            // repaint();
        }

        public void mouseReleased ( MouseEvent me ) {
            r = me.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseDragged ( MouseEvent me ) {
            r = me.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```